# Mongoose Model find using an attribute from anohter Schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Basically I have 2 Schemas.

User and Post.

User have an array which contains _ids from posts.
And post have an attribute that tells if he's an active post. -> is_active.
So, i want to filter User that have at least, one active post.

**UserSchema**

```
const UserSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true
    },
    posts: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Post'
      }
    ],
    created_at: {
      type: Date,
      required: true,
      default: Date.now()
    }
  }
)

export default mongoose.model<User>('User', UserSchema)
```

**Post Schema**

```
const postSchema = new Schema(
     {
       name: String,
       is_active: boolean
     }
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to @Tunmee's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63124588)

Since the pipeline `$lookup` is available from v3.6 and as of v4.2 still has some performance [issues](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-32549). You could also use the "regular" `$lookup` available from v3.2

```
db.Users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Posts",
      localField: "posts",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "posts"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "posts.is_active": true
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Posts",
      let: { postIds: "$posts", },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $in: [ "$_id", "$$postIds" ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [ "$is_active", true ]
                },
              ]
            }
          },
        },
        // You can remove the projection below 
        // if you need the actual posts data in the final result
        {
          $project: { _id: 1 }
        }
      ],
      as: "posts"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [ { $size: "$posts" }, 0 ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can test it out in a playground [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yVIzFbpeq15)

I'm not sure about your application's query requirement but you can add a [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/index.html) on `_id` and `is_active` properties in Posts collection to make the query faster.

You can read more about MongoDB data aggregation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/).

Comment: Thank you!!! That worked for me.
And thank you for showing me Mongo Playground.
That's a found for me :)